# Initialization by conversion function for direct reference binding

Tags: c++, reference, overload-resolution

I found out the rules for determining the candidate conversion functions, for direct reference binding, are not described clearly by the standard at least for me.

The rules are found in [over.match.ref]

> Under the conditions specified in [dcl.init.ref], a reference can be
> bound directly to the result of applying a conversion function to an
> initializer expression. Overload resolution is used to select the
> conversion function to be invoked. Assuming that “reference to cv1 T”
> is the type of the reference being initialized, the candidate
> functions are selected as follows:
>
> - (1.1) Let R be a set of types including
>
>   - (1.1.1) “lvalue reference to cv2 T2” (when initializing an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference to function) and
>   - (1.1.2) “cv2 T2” and “rvalue reference to cv2 T2” (when initializing an rvalue reference or an lvalue reference to function) for any T2.
>
> The permissible types for non-explicit conversion functions are the
> members of R where “cv1 T” is reference-compatible ([dcl.init.ref])
> with “cv2 T2”. For direct-initialization, the permissible types for
> explicit conversion functions are the members of R where T2 can be
> converted to type T with a (possibly trivial) qualification conversion
> ([conv.qual]); otherwise there are none.

As far as I understood, I can say that when initializing an "lvalue reference to cv1 T" the conversion function is a candidate if and only if it returns "lvalue reference to cv2 T2", where “cv1 T” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”.

And when initializing an "rvalue reference to cv1 T", the conversion function is a candidate if and only if it returns "rvalue reference to cv2 T2" or "cv T2", where “cv1 T” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”. Right?

Assuming my understanding is correct, here is a question. Why do we even need a conversion function to convert from cv2 T2 to cv1 T even though “cv1 T” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”?

Can you clearly explain the bullet (1.1) with some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do we even need a conversion function to convert from cv2 T2 to cv1 T even though “cv1 T” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”?

Because only after the conversion is done(using the conversion function), the result is of type `cv2 T2`. In other words, the result of using/calling the conversion function is `cv2 T2` and not whatever expression you have before using the conversion function. This is the whole point of using a conversion function so that we can something that is reference compatible with `cv1 T`.

Lets look at some examples:

##### Example 1

```
struct C {
   operator int&(); 
};

const int& ref= C();
```

In the above example, the type `cv1 T = const int` is **not reference-compatible** with the *class-type* `C`. But due to the presence of the conversion function `C::operator int&()`, a given `C` can be converted to an *lvalue* of type `cv2 T2 = int`. And we know that `const int` is reference compatible with `int`. This means that the reference `ref` can be bound to the result of the conversion function according to your quoted clause.

##### Example 2

This example 2 does not uses a conversion function but i've added this just to clarify the explanation given at the beginning of my answer.

```
double val = 4.55;   
const int &ref = val;
```

In the above example, the type `cv1 T = const int` is **not reference-compatible** with the type `double`. And at the end, the reference `ref` is bound to a materialized temporary(prvalue) of type `cv2 T2 = int`. This is possible because `const int` is reference compatible with the type of the materialized temporary `int`.

The important thing to note here is that a temporary is materialized because originally `cv1 T = const int` was not reference compatible with `double`. But after the materialization, `cv1 T = const int` is reference compatible with the result `cv2 T2 = int`.

Comment: `As far as I understood, I can say that when initializing an "lvalue reference to cv1 T" ...` Is my understanding correct?

`

Comment: @Morise Yes exactly.

Comment: Also if you can, I need an explanation for that section: "_The permissible types for non-explicit conversion functions are the members of R where “cv1 T” is reference-compatible ([dcl.init.ref]) with “cv2 T2”. For direct-initialization, the permissible types..._"

Comment: @Morise It means that say if there were two conversion functions available like for [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Y5csEKe1r): `struct C {operator int&(); operator double&();};` then the set `R` would only contain the type corresponding to the first conversion operator `C::operator int&()` and not corresponding to the second conversion function `C::operator double&()`.

Comment: "_then the set R would only contain the type corresponding to the first conversion operator C::operator int&() and not corresponding to the second conversion function C::operator double&()_" That's because the referred-to type of the reference being initialized `cv1 T = const int` is reference-compatible with the result of applying the conversion function `cv2 T2 = int`, and it is not reference-compatible with `cv2 T2 = double` Correct reason?

Comment: And I have a last question - In this initialization "const int& ref= C();" Does `ref` is bind _directly_ to the result of applying conversion function, or does it binds to a temporary? I think it binds directly because the initializer expression results in an lvalue reference binds directly to an lvalue, therefore, `ref` binds also directly to that lvalue. Right?

Comment: @Morise Yes, `ref` binds to the `lvalue` and not to a temporary in the example 1 given in my answer. And yes, your previous comment is also correct. That is, you've understood correctly.